# getElementById().getElementsByTagName() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

While using `getElementById().getElementsByTagName()` it's not getting objects in IE8.  For example:

```
var devang = getElementById('devang').getElementsByTagName('li');
alert(devang.length);
```

it's return length of objects, while in IE8 it's shows value 0;

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8vmz/)

Comment: What is the actual error (or something) you're getting back?  If you just call `getElementById` what goes into `devang` because this is core browser stuff and does work.

Comment: `gEBI()` is a method of `document` not `window`, your code won't work in any browser.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? Are you sure you have an element with the id `devang` that is an `ul`? Note that `getElementsByTagName()` gets child elements, it will not work if the id `devang` is on the `li`.

Comment: [code] var devang = document.getElementById('devang').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i=0; i<devang.length; i++) {
        devang[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
 alert(devang.length);
[code]

above code also works fine in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another quick solution

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

above html5shive.min.js add in your header your code will be working nicely in internet explorer 8.

more details you can study on [google code html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
 var devang = document.getElementById('devang').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: @DevangSolanki Yes but an hour ago when this was answered your code looked like:                                                     `sample var devang = getElementById('devang').getElementsByTagName('li');`

Comment: might be :) I am very new buddy here

Comment: @DevangSolanki That's fine, this answer is obsolete now anyways. Obviously you meant to put this code above at the start.